# Flutter Could not get unknown property 'plugin' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project. Error

Tags: android, flutter

I am getting this error when running my Flutter app:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Dosyalar\Yaz�l�m\Flutter\Simto-To-Do-List\simto_todolist\android\app\build.gradle' line: 23

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'plugin' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BU�LD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

I started getting this error after I changed the location of my Flutter project.

Codes at `android\app\build.gradle` mentioned in the error:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}
apply plugin 'com.android.application' // line 23
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "io.simto.todolist.app"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.2.1')
}
```

This is the first time I encountered this problem. Why am I getting this error? How can I solve it? Thanks in advance for your help.

Good day.

Answer (score 1):

In the line 23, `:` is missing after `apply plugin`.
To solve the problem, change line 23 to:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```